# Error: Argument not specified for parameter

Tags: database, vb.net, windows, ms-access-2007

I am creating a solution to a particular database problem.  I want to add a new product to my DB, but I am getting these two errors:

> Error 1   Argument not specified for parameter 'PershkrimiProduktit' of 'Public Overridable Overloads Function Insert(KodiProduktit As String, EmriProduktit As String, CmimiBlerjes As Decimal?, CmimiShitjes As Decimal?, SasiaProduktit As String, PershkrimiProduktit As String) As Integer'. C:\Users\Brilian\Desktop\POS\GUI\AddItem.vb 71  13  POS
>
> Error 2   Argument not specified for parameter 'SasiaProduktit' of 'Public Overridable Overloads Function Insert(KodiProduktit As String, EmriProduktit As String, CmimiBlerjes As Decimal?, CmimiShitjes As Decimal?, SasiaProduktit As String, PershkrimiProduktit As String) As Integer'.  C:\Users\Brilian\Desktop\POS\GUI\AddItem.vb 71  13  POS

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ' performojme verivikimin
        ' perform validation for barcode
        If TextBox1.Text.Trim = "" Then
            MsgBox("You should enter a barcode number", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
            TextBox1.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
            MsgBox("The barcode number should include digits only", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
            TextBox1.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If TextBox1.Text.Contains(".") Or TextBox1.Text.Contains("-") Then
            MsgBox("The barcode number should include digits only", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
            TextBox1.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' perform check for the item name
        If TextBox2.Text.Trim = "" Then
            MsgBox("You should enter name for the item", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
            TextBox2.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' perform a check for the buy price
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBox3.Text) Then
            MsgBox("You should enter the buy price as a number", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
            TextBox3.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim ÇmimiBlerjes As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
        If ÇmimiBlerjes < 0 Then
            MsgBox("Buy price can't be negative", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
            TextBox3.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' perform a check for the sell price
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBox4.Text) Then
            MsgBox("You should enter the sell price as a number", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
            TextBox4.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim ÇmimiShitjes As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(TextBox4.Text)
        If ÇmimiShitjes < 0 Then
            MsgBox("Sell price can't be negative", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
            TextBox4.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If ÇmimiShitjes <= ÇmimiBlerjes Then
            MsgBox("Sell price can't be less than buy price", MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
            TextBox4.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' insert the item
        Try
            ' create the adapter
            Dim TA As New POSDSTableAdapters.ItemsTableAdapter

            ' insert the item
            TA.Insert(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, ÇmimiBlerjes, ÇmimiShitjes)

            ' close window and return ok
            Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
        Catch ex As Exception

            ' display error message
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical Or MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It seems pretty clear from the error message. TA.Insert needs 6 parameters, you are passing just 4. Where are the other two?

Comment: i dont know how to add them any ideas?

Comment: Adding them is not a problem, what they mean and where to get them is not possible to say from your code. Add another two textboxes and ask your user to input them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear.  The `Insert` method requires the following six parameters:

- `KodiProduktit As String`
- `EmriProduktit As String`
- `CmimiBlerjes As Decimal?`
- `CmimiShitjes As Decimal?`
- `SasiaProduktit As String`
- `PershkrimiProduktit As String`

But, when you call it, you are only passing it four parameters:

- `TextBox1.Text`
- `TextBox2.Text`
- `ÇmimiBlerjes`
- `ÇmimiShitjes`

You need to pass two more parameters to the `Insert` method, namely `SasiaProduktit` and `PershkrimiProduktit` (both strings).  If you do not have values for those parameters, you should be able to simply pass `Nothing`, like this:

```
TA.Insert(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, ÇmimiBlerjes, ÇmimiShitjes, Nothing, Nothing)
```

Or empty strings:

```
TA.Insert(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, ÇmimiBlerjes, ÇmimiShitjes, "", "")
```

Comment: Ok whats this now Warning 1 Variable 'SasiaProduktit' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime. C:\Users\Brilian\Desktop\POS\GUI\AddItem.vb 74 81 POS                                                 Warning 2 Variable 'PershkrimiProduktit' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime. C:\Users\Brilian\Desktop\POS\GUI\AddItem.vb 74 97 POS

Comment: Is `SasiaProduktit` a new variable that you added since you posted the code in your question?  I don't see it anywhere in your code.

Comment: Sasiaproduktit is in the db table that i created with msaccess 2007    now i want to add info on it so it can be displayed on my datagrid view

Comment: That warning is, again, very clear.  It means exactly what it says.  I'm not sure how I could make it any more clear.  Somewhere in the `AddItem.vb` file, you have declared a variable called `SasiaProduktit`.  You then are using the `SasiaProduktit` variable before you ever set it to a value.  That may not be a problem at all, though.  That's why it's just a warning.  If it's not an issue, just set the variable to `Nothing` when you declare it to get rid of the warning.

Comment: THNX very much m8 i replaced those two with the nothing and i deleted the sasiaproduktit and pershkrimiproduktit form the db and dataset , it work now thnx alot